# D3 tickFormat not showing expected values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

*xAxis* has an ordinal scale in terms of dates. *dateLabelMap* contains labels for precalculated tick dates. When I set tickValues to the keys of *dateLabelMap* - the dates - the *d* in the tickFormat function is sometimes a date not in Object.keys(*dateLabelMap*). How is this happening? Does tickFormat not fully rely on tickValues for the *d* values? How can I fix this so every value of *d* is every value of Object.keys(*dateLabelMap*)?

```
xAxis
    .scale(x)
    .tickValues(Object.keys(dateLabelMap))
    .tickFormat(function(d,i) {

        if (d in dateLabelMap) {
            return dateLabelMap[d];         
        }           

        return "";
    });
```

EDIT: example: If I change the code to the following:

```
var correctDates = [];
var extraDates = [];
xAxis
    .scale(x)
    .tickValues(Object.keys(dateLabelMap))
    .tickFormat(function(d,i) {

        if (d in dateLabelMap) {
            correctDates.push(d);
            return dateLabelMap[d];         
        }           

         extraDates.push(d);
        return "";
    });
```

After the last iteration, I get:
Object.keys(*dateLabelMap*) contains:

```
0: "Fri Nov 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
1: "Sun Dec 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
2: "Tue Dec 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
3: "Sat Feb 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
4: "Fri Feb 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
5: "Tue Apr 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
6: "Wed Apr 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
7: "Fri May 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
8: "Thu Jun 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
9: "Tue Jul 29 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
10: "Fri Aug 29 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
11: "Wed Oct 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
12: "Thu Oct 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
13: "Wed Nov 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
14: "Mon Dec 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
15: "Thu Jan 29 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
16: "Thu Feb 19 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
```

*correctDates* contains:

```
0: "Sun Dec 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
1: "Tue Dec 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
2: "Sat Feb 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
3: "Fri Feb 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
4: "Tue Apr 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
5: "Wed Apr 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
6: "Fri May 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
7: "Thu Jun 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
8: "Tue Jul 29 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
9: "Thu Oct 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
10: "Wed Nov 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
11: "Mon Dec 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
12: "Thu Jan 29 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
13: "Thu Feb 19 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
```

*extraDates* contains:

```
0: Sat Nov 16 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
1: Thu Jul 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Shouldn't *correctDates* be identical to Object.keys(*dateLabelMap*) and *extraDates* not exist?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Are you changing tickFormat for every d?

Comment: @Klaujesi I am returning a different label for each d, yes.

Comment: JavaScript returns a value from 0 to 11. January is 0, February is 1, and so on. Have you the right data?

Comment: @Klaujesi No mater what the data is, I am expecting correctDates to be the same as Object.keys(dateLabelMap). Is this an incorrect assumption? If so, why?